# What is the sum of quadratic function?

Tags: exponential-sum

I would like to know the result of the summation of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{500}e^{i2{\pi}{an^2}/(b+cn)}$, in which a, b, and c are real constant value.

No need for an exact solution, an approximation would be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: I searched over the internet, but does not find anything useful. Someone mentioned Jacobi theta function, but I cannot follow it.